# Access to class attributes by using a variable in Python?

Tags: python, attributes

In PHP I can access class attributes like this:

```
<?php // very simple :)
class TestClass {}
$tc = new TestClass{};
$attribute = 'foo';
$tc->{$attribute} = 'bar';
echo $tc->foo
// should echo 'bar'
```

How can I do this in Python?

```
class TestClass()
tc = TestClass
attribute = 'foo'
# here comes the magic?
print tc.foo
# should echo 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked several times. You can use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the attribute by name:

```
print getattr(tc, 'foo')
```

This works for methods as well:

```
getattr(tc, 'methodname')(arg1, arg2)
```

To set an attribute by name use [setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
setattr(tc, 'foo', 'bar')
```

To check if an attribute exists use [hasattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr)

```
hasattr(tc, 'foo')
```

Comment: Another useful detail on getattr: it takes a third (optional) argument, which supplies the default value if the attribute is not found.  If this argument is not supplied, then an exception is raised if the attribute is not found (AttributeError).

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestClass(object)
    pass

tc = TestClass()
setattr(tc, "foo", "bar")
print tc.foo
```